# Profiling view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, view, profiling

I have a big view, which takes very long to finish to render the content. How is the best method to profile, which part of the view is taking the most time ? I have read about ruby-prof, but I'm not sure, where to put in it, to profile the view rendering. If other options exists, I want to know them too.

Comment: the logs tell how much takes each partial to render. You could split your view to check.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to quickly get to bottleneck is using NewRelics Developer mode which works locally.

1. Make sure you have `ruby-prof` and `newrelic_rpm` in your Gemfile.
2. Navigate to `localhost:3000/newrelic` and start profiling (in the right bar)
3. Make an actual request to page of your app you want to profile, possibly multiple times to make sure you don't measure some caching & stuff.
4. Navigate back to newrelic developer mode, pick request trace.
5. Sort the table by "self" column. This is crucial since the default sorting by total time is misleading.
6. Look on top-10 calls, how are they called and you probably find the bottleneck.

Disclaimer: I've pushed this sorting feature to newrelic's developer mode, so I am biased. However try if for yourself.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but `localhost:3000/newrelic` is no longer available as of the version i'm using today, which is `newrelic_rpm 4.8.0.341`

Comment: "Developer mode is removed and no longer supported as of Ruby agent version 4.1.0." https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/features/developer-mode Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy, actually. I just found and fixed a performance problem with a HAML template using `ruby-prof`. The relevant part of the template looked something like:

```
  - @collection.each do |x|
    = render :partial => 'name', :locals => {:object => x}
```

I made sure `ruby-prof` was in the Gemfile and temporarily changed that to:

```
  - require 'ruby-prof'
  - RubyProf.start
  - @collection.each do |x|
    = render :partial => 'name', :locals => {:object => x}
  - result = RubyProf.stop
  - printer = RubyProf::CallStackPrinter.new(result)
  - file = File.open('profile.html', 'w')
  - printer.print(file)
  - file.close
```

Then boot up the app, hit the page a couple times, and open up the newly created `profile.html` in my browser to see which part was causing the problem.

Comment: thanks for this - I got stuck with a slow view issue, and I did exactly this to find my problem. FWIW - my problem was a table of entries with a column that could be edited in place using best_in_place. Turns out having a bip field with a huge list of options for every row doesn't render that quickly!

Answer (score 1):

NewRelic and the logs are helpful, but sometimes you need more. NewRelic does have a free tool that can help you dig locally, and tools like ruby-prof will give you info, but it can be hard to know what to do with it.

I came across a sign up page in a client's app what was ridiculously slow, for no apparent reason. The logs confirmed that it was slow, and that the slowness was not due to the db, but didn't help me see what the issue was.

https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug/

Is easier to use than ruby-prof, and can be turned on/off quickly when you need to dive into something. I use it all the time when helping people tune their Rails apps. It helped me understand which partial was slow, and with a little trial and error, I discovered it was the drop down for timezones on the sign up page

On one page it was (the slow version):
    <%= time_zone_select :user, :time_zone, TZInfo::Country.get("US").zones, {} %>

and another was:
    <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone,  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, :default => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" %>

My before/after numbers:

```
orig template render          1392.91
fixed template render         165.56
fixed on REE instead of 1.8.7 100.70
```

I didn't dig any further, as I had other issues to fix, but it would be possible to cache the timezones and get an even faster response.

Comment: how did you end up fixing this? We are seeing the same thing - there are 4 pages in our app that render time zones (US only) and they consistently take more than 1200ms to render. Take the line out and it's like 140ms total.

Comment: I just used ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones instead of TZInfo::Country.get("US").zones.

Comment: Odd - we actually were using ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones. Come to thing of it this might help - we actually added an initializer to the app to load the time zones - just set it to a local variable. What we found is that hte first call lo load time zones took forever but after that they were snappy. So adding the initializer call solved the issue for us - takes an extra second to load the app but no performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not do it, check folder `log` in application folder first. It contains log files for every environment of your app.

In order to profile a rails app, put your tests to folder `your_app/test/profile`

http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/

Comment: This provide no information about which part of the view takes the most time, and env/logs from the application give only rough times, for example how long took a partial to render.